# Given root, how can I get an inputStream out of a protected file?

Tags: android, file, inputstream, root

Suppose I got root access inside the app, how can I get to create an InputStream out of a file that's in a protected folder (for example, to get a Bitmap object out of a jpeg file) ?

I could just copy the file to somewhere that I can handle normally, but is it possible to just use an InputStream directly?

Maybe I should print the content of the file, and get this as the inputStream?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found a workaround for this. Here are the steps:

1. get file access, using **stat -c "%a" FILEPATH** command
2. change file access, using **chmod 646 FILEPATH** command.
3. create a new symlink to the file, using **ln -s FILEPATH SYMLINK_FILE_PATH** command.
4. read from the symlink file using Java, as if it's a normal file.
5. restore the file access of the file, as shown on #1, and delete the symlink file, if you wish.

Still, I would like to know if it's possible to use an alternative solution.